# error using Load with JLD

Tags: load, julia

I used JLD to save and load data to plot the results of some experiment. It has always worked fine until recently when I tryed to load a more heavy (usually it was around 5 to 20 MB and now from 400 to 500 MB, I dont know if this is the problem though.), and I obtain :

```
Fatal error: 

 ERROR: UndefVarError: load not defined


 Stacktrace:   
[1] #load#27(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function,
 ::FileIO.File{FileIO.DataFormat{:HDF5}}) at
 /Users/blabla/.julia/v0.6/FileIO/src/loadsave.jl:180   
[2]
 load(::FileIO.File{FileIO.DataFormat{:HDF5}}) at
 /Users/blabla/.julia/v0.6/FileIO/src/loadsave.jl:167   
[3]
 #load#13(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::String) at /Users/blabla/.julia/v0.6/FileIO/src/loadsave.jl:113   
[4]
 load(::String) at /Users/blabla/.julia/v0.6/FileIO/src/loadsave.jl:113
```

I tryed to update HDF5 and JLD but everything seems well installed... and I havent found any size limits for JLD on the documentation.

Can anyone help with that?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you your copy the line of code that triggered this error?

Comment: `using JLD: load
expe=load("name.jld");
 `
the same code still works when loading my former data sets.

Comment: what is the output of "file /path/to/working/file" and "file /path/to/problematic/file" ? (if you have the file command installed)

Comment: I don't have it installed and I cannot find it (I don't find relevant keywords to look for it), could you please provide a link explaining how to install it please?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried loading a recently saved `SimpleWeightedGraph`. It happened because `SparseArrays` was not being imported and the weights of a weighted graph are saved as a `SparseArray`. JLD was trying to load a SparseArray but there was no `SparseArray` type available in the namespace.

Just putting a `using SparseArrays` fixed it.

It could be that you missed an import statement for whatever type JLD is trying to load.